# nodejs del: use absolute path

Tags: node.js, node-glob

I'd like to absolute paths with sindresorhus' [node del plugin](https://github.com/sindresorhus/del) (or really `node-glob`) but it doesn't seem to work. I tried fiddling around with [node-glob's options](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#options) like `cwd` and `root`, but didn't get it to work.

Any idea anyone? One of my attempts:

```js
var path = require('path');
var del = require('del');
var root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..'); // this could be more involved..

var delOptions = {
  cwd: root,
  force: true
};

del([
  'browser/dist/**',
], delOptions, function (err, paths) {
  console.log('removed files:');
  console.log('- ' + paths.join('\n- '));
});
```